# run a Quartz.NET job as "user" - permissions issue

Tags: quartz-scheduler

**Scenario:**
I have a console application that needs to access a network share with read/write permissions.
There is no problems when run it manually.

**The problem:**
When I add this application as a job in my quartz.net server, it cannot access the share. I do not have access to change permissions on the network share, so basically I need my quartz job or if necessary my quartz server to run jobs as me (or as a user that has the proper permissions).

Any ideas in how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use [impersonation](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2005/03/21/400088.aspx) to change the user you're running as on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the user that the service is ran with (so this actually isn't a Quartz.NET issue). Open service properties in services and change the user from SYSTEM or NETWORK SERVICE to some named user account that has proper rights to the network share.