# Quartz.NET and Windows Identity

Tags: quartz.net

How do you specify the Windows Identity that jobs scheduled through Quartz.NET run as?  I need to schedule jobs to get the free drive space of servers on our network.  When I run the code without using Quartz.NET it runs as the Windows Account that I have specified through IIS.  However, when I take that same code and move it to the Execute function of a job class it does NOT run as the proper account but rather as the basic ASPNET account.  So, when I run the scheduled jobs I am getting an ACCESS DENIED error at Scope.Connect().

```
public class Scheduler
{
    public static void InitializeScheduler()
    {
        ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        IScheduler sched = sf.GetScheduler();

        JobDetail job = new JobDetail("job1", "group1", typeof(GetFreeSpace));
        CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger("trigger1", "group1", "job1", "group1", "0 0 10 ? * MON");
        sched.AddJob(job, true);
        sched.ScheduleJob(trigger);

        sched.Start();
    }
}

public class GetFreeSpace : IJob
{
    public void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
    {
        ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("Server", options);
            scope.Connect();
}
}
```

Comment: Are you hosting Quartz in your ASP.NET app?

Comment: Yes, Quartz is embedded in the ASP.NET app.  However, I already found my answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883161/run-a-quartz-net-job-as-user-permissions-issue).  I had impersonation set-up in the web.config and it was working fine in other areas of the code.  But for the Quartz.NET jobs I had to use a different impersonation method for it to work.

Comment: Ryan, could you write up your answer here, please? I'm interested to see how you used the impersonation method shown in the accepted answer in the linked question to solve the issue from inside ASP.NET. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ryan, I have the exact same issue. Do you mind writing up your solution here as an answer?